# Difference between avg_data_io_percent vs. avg_log_write_percent in sys.dm_db_resource_stats

Tags: azure-sql-database

In the sys.dm_db_resource_stats DMV there are two columns named avg_data_io_percent and avg_log_write_percent. These are two of three columns in the DMV used to calculate DTUs. What's not clear to me is the exact difference between the two. Of course, avg_log_write_percent is a measure of writes being made to the database. What's not as clear is what avg_data_io represents. Wouldn't this include writes as well (along with reads)?

Answer (score 1):

**avg-data-io**:
Represents both reads and writes for any query and this doesn't include log writes

**Avg-log-io:**
Represents log written to disk.Assume you have a DML Statement like below

```
update t
set col1=4
```

SQLSERVER writes this operation to log file to replay it incase of rollback.This percentages of writes comes under Avg-log-io

I was able to repro log-io with a simple test for my basic tier.Running below query on a table with one million rows exploded log io,but data io is less during this period ,which may be due to all the required data is in memory

```
update orders 
set filler='z'
```

**log io after update:**

[image]

Further if you are looking to tune queries which are running slow, one simple rule i follow is to observe cpuio,dataio,logio,memory..If any of these four average consistently over 90 over a period of time..I would try to  get those queries and tune them..

for example, if CPU averages over 90 over a period of time, then i would get the queries which are causing high cpu and tune them

you may also find this article interesting ,but beware these are approximate values:https://sqlperformance.com/2017/03/azure/what-the-heck-is-a-dtu